# W/System ( 7739): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null. in flutter Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

when i try to enter password it is showing the message
how to fix this, and its not showing the wrong password error snackbar as per the code.
here is my code

```
 Future signIn(context) async {
    try {
      if (emailController.text.isEmpty) {
        snackBar(context, 'Enter Email');
      } else if (passwordController.text.isEmpty) {
        snackBar(context, 'Enter password');
      } else {
        await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: emailController.text.trim(),
          password: passwordController.text.trim(),
        );
        navigatorKey.currentState!.popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);
      }
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
        snackBar(context, 'wrong-password');
      } else if (e.code == Failures.user_not_found) {
        snackBar(context, 'user-not-found');
      } else if (e.code == Failures.invalid_email) {
        snackBar(context, 'invalid-email');
      } else if (e.code == Failures.user_disabled) {
        snackBar(context, 'Your account is disabled');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

the fun part is it was working fine by yesterday

Comment: Please check if Firebase rules are set properly

Comment: i set this all up again, now its working, but still showing the message, even tho its working, why is that showing

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled the Email/Password Sign-in method on your Firebase console?

[image]

Comment: yes i enabled the method

Comment: Add usesCleartextTraffic="true" in androidmanifest.xml.